# Dividing exponent with same base

Tags: exponentiation

There are $~2^{80}~$ possibilities to calculate and I want to divide it by $~2~$ to process it by two computers at the same time to find the answer maybe sooner.

How can I divide  $~2^{80}~$ by $~2~$?

Comment: Do you mean $\frac{2^{80}}{2} = 2^{80-1} = 2^{79}$? or something else?

Comment: @mlchristians yes exactly.

Comment: Well, there you have it.

Comment: @mlchristiansThanks.

Comment: @mlchristians how about dividing it to 100? the answer would be (2/5)^2*2^76?

Comment: $\frac{2^{80}}{100} = \frac{2^{80}}{2^{2}5^{2}} = \frac{2^{78}}{5^{2}}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac {2^{80}}2=\frac{2^{80}}{2^1}=2^{80-1}=2^{79}$$
Having two computers does not make much of a dent.

Comment: How about 1000 Computer?  Army of Zombies.

Comment: $1000 \approx 2^{10}$ so it still doesn't help much.  $2^{80}$ is *really* big.

Comment: Is there any way to compute this big number by using parallel processing?

Comment: Computing the number is easy.  [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E80) gives $1208925819614629174706176$ instantly.  It will do much larger numbers as well. If you know $2^{10}=1024$ it only takes three more multiplies to get there, which is reasonable to do by hand.  Doing that many operations in a computer is hard.  If you can do $10^{12}$ per second it will take about $10^{12}$ seconds, which is about $30000$ years.

Comment: I am looking for an idea or at least a clue to compute that big number using too many computers but with your good answer, I think it is somehow impossible.

Comment: To compute the number you just need some software that works with numbers that do not fit into $64$ bits.  Wolfram Alpha does that and is available at www.wolframalpha.com.  You can just type in 2^80 and get the result.  You can do much larger numbers.  The programming language Python switches seamlessly into large integers when required.  It does $2^{8000}, which has about $2400$ digits instantly.  There is an add-on package to C that will handle large numbers, but I am not familiar with it.  Maple and Mathematica will do this.  I suspect there are add-ons for any popular programming language

Comment: When you started it sounded like you wanted to compute $2^{80}$ different things, which is wildly different.  No array of computers can reasonably do that.

Comment: It is actually part of my project about cracking RSA 1024, to do that I have to compute all combination but it takes many years as you mentioned then I decide to break it to many computers to reduce the computing time, here is the link to the original question: [How long does it take to crack RSA 1024 with a PC?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/70829/60359)

Comment: My second comment is very rough but in the spirit of your linked question.  $10^{12}$ operations per second seems large to me.  With $30000$ computers you could be done in a year.

Comment: But is it not possible that maybe one of these 30000 computers has the answer before all possibility being computed?

Comment: Absolutely.  You could hit it on the first guess.  Very unlikely, though.